# How can i add up a total value from identical items in a list?

Tags: python, list

(sorry if the title doesn't make sense, i have no idea how to phrase this)

So i'm trying to make a python program that grabs a users nationality and score from a leaderboard and tally up all of the points from all of the users in a specific country.

> Ex: Adding up all the points of users from the US would give a total score.

All of the user data (top 1000 best users) is saved in a JSON file.

Here's all the code I've written.

```
import json


with open('bl1000.json', encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

countries = []
     
uniquecountries = []

pps = []

output = {}

#collect data
for i in data['data']:
    cur_cou = i['country']
    if cur_cou not in uniquecountries:
        uniquecountries.append(cur_cou)
    else:
        continue  
    
for i in data['data']:
    cur_cou = i['country']
    countries.append(cur_cou)

for i in data['data']:
    cur_pp = i['pp']
    pps.append(cur_pp)
```

All of this works, I'm just stuck on the whole "tally up the scores for each country" part.
Any help would be appreciated and i'm sorry if this is hard to understand, as it's very hard to explain.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the JSON data to work with?

Comment: Don't keep a list.  Keep a dictionary, where the key is the country name and the value is the sum of points.  One pass through the data.  `if i['country'] not in scores:` / `scores[i['country']] = 0` / `scores[i['country']] += i['pp']`.  You could use a `defaultdict` to reduce that to one line.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't think this works as a comment. It's either an answer or you walk away. It's too hard to read

Comment: "and i'm sorry if this is hard to understand, as it's very hard to explain." - Tasks like this are normally not hard to explain at all; you just have to think clearly about them and talk through it in order. What do you mean by "identical"? What does the input look like, and what should the output look like for the example input that you show us? Step by step, how is that result calculated?

Comment: @JRiggles the json data gives a lot of data for one user, so heres just the lines i need to read.
"pp": 22597.04,
"country": "US",

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 

My goal is to add up the combined score of all users from the same country, and repeat this for all countries that have users. (could also be phrased as "not including countries that have no users")

Comment: What "users"? What "countries"? We can't see your data, therefore we can't be sure of how to analyze it in order to get information like that.

Comment: @roganjosh -- Yes, but for that I blame SO.  There are many cases where code is needed that don't qualify as an answer, and I'm not going to "walk away".  This is especially an issue when questions are closed prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to track the scores.  One pass through.

```
#collect data
scores = {}
for i in data['data']:
    cur_cou = i['country']
    if cur_cou not in uniquecountries:
        scores[cur_cou] = 0
    scores[cur_cou] += i['pp']
```

Then, to see the results:

```
for cou,total in scores.items():
    print(cou, total)
```

Comment: when running this, it gives a proper output, but it doesnt seem to be correct. I'll use the US as an example. It returns `US 12441.203`. This cant be right, because this is way too low. Every user in my database has a score above 10000, and (through another script) i found that over 300 of the users are from the us.

Comment: Did you, perhaps, type `=` instead of `+=` when copying the final line?  This code must work, but without having your data file, there's no way for me to tell.